# Custom divider in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I have a custom layout for my recycler view with an image view and a text view(in a horizontal linear layout). I needed a custom behaviour for my divider - divider should show only under the textview area and not the image view area. For example, whatsapp's chat list view - [link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MMue08byixTw74ST_VkNQDUUJBgVEbjNHDYLhIuHmYhMIMJIp3KjVlnhhqZQOZUtNt8=h900)

When I use the default DividerItemDecoration, it creates a divider across the view.

How do I achieve a custom Divider which spans only certain views?

Comment: Did you try setting android:divider="@android:color/transparent" for image view in the recycle view ?

Comment: I am not being able to set a android:divider attribute for an image view in the recycler view item layout.

Comment: Yeah you need to have two linear layout one for image view and other for  text view and the linear layout which contains image should have the android:divider="@android:color/transparent" value.

Comment: This method did not work.

Comment: I made it work using a different way by overriding onDraw

Comment: Great it would be helpful to others if u answer yourself.

Comment: Yes I added my answer :) not a very generic solution, but I guess it will portray the solution for others to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this here - https://gist.github.com/shiladitya-bits/1444002568de9f02ce3d

```
View avoidView = child.findViewById(avoidResourceId); 
if(avoidView != null){
    width = avoidView.getWidth(); 
} 
mDivider.setBounds(left+width, top, right, bottom);
```